# pointer to the function in C++,are (*pf)() and pf same?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a beginner in C++ and I have a problem understanding pointers to functions:

```
main()
{
    double pam(int);
    double (*pf)(int);
    pf = pam;            
    double x = pam(4);    
    double y = (*pf)(5); 
    double y = pf(5);
}
```

How can `(*pf)()` and `pf()` be the same, where `pf` is a pointer to the function?

What is the difference between other pointers and a pointer to the function??

Comment: you're going to find this question and answers highly enlightening: [How do function pointers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Comment: Fun note: try adding some more `*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how can *pf() and pf() be the same where pf is a pointer to the function?

They aren't the same (because of operator precedence). In case you meant `(*pf)()` and `pf()` are effectively the same, then that's because the rules of the language say so. Specifically, the rules say:

> [expr.call]
>
> A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function.
>   The postfix expression shall have function type or function pointer type.
>   For a call to a non-member function or to a static member function, the postfix expression shall either be an lvalue that refers to a function (in which case the function-to-pointer standard conversion ([conv.func]) is suppressed on the postfix expression), or have function pointer type.

In case of `(*pf)()`, the expression `(*pf)` is an lvalue that refers to a function, while in the case of `pf()`, the expression `pf` has a function pointer type. In both cases the function pointed by `pf` is called.

> What is the difference between other pointers and a pointer to the function??

The primary difference is that function pointers point to functions, and pointers to objects point to objects.

Comment: And functions are one of the few things in C++ that aren't objects.

Comment: @Scheff You're correct. I copied that part from the question, and forgot that the parentheses are needed. I've fixed the answer.